# how to set Window Width and Window Center while convert a dicom file to a jpg file

Tags: python, opencv, dicom

I don't know how to set Window Width Window Center while convert a dicom file to a jpg file.

I finished a convertor application which can convert a dicom file to a jpg file by python and opencv.

But it has a great difference between dicom file and jpg file, cause i didn't set the Window Width and Window Center.However i don't know how to set it.

The Window Center is -400 and the Window Width is 1500.

Here is my code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import cv2
import dicom

def convert_file(dcm_file_path, jpg_file_path):
    dicom_img = dicom.read_file(dcm_file_path)
    img = dicom_img.pixel_array
    cv2.imwrite(jpg_file_path, img)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rootdir = "D:\CT\A7"

    for parent, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootdir):
        for filename in filenames:
            if '.dcm' in filename.lower():
                dicom_path = os.path.join(parent, filename)
                name = dicom_path.replace('\\', '_')[3:]
                jpg_path = "d:\CT_JPG\\%s.jpg" % name
                print (jpg_path)
                convert_file(dicom_path, jpg_path)
```

Comment: Changing the windowing wouldn't really help since you're using the pixel data itself.  the window center and window width properties are for display purposes on DICOM viewers.

To see a change in the jpg image you'll need to change the pixel data itself (which is in HU)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to save the DICOM image as a jpg, rather than playing around with Window Width and Window Center parameters, which as suggested in the comments, are meant for ease of viewing, I would recommend simply normalizing the scale of the image (which is in `int16`) to `uint8` (which is the scale of normal jpg/png/gif images). Do note However, that this would cause a loss in resolution.

To save it as a jpg, one possible way would be to make the following modification:

```
def convert_file(dcm_file_path, jpg_file_path):
    dicom_img = dicom.read_file(dcm_file_path)
    img = dicom_img.pixel_array
    scaled_img = cv2.convertScaleAbs(img-np.min(img), alpha=(255.0 / min(np.max(img)-np.min(img), 10000)))
    cv2.imwrite(jpg_file_path, scaled_img)
```

If you want to do it about a fixed Window Center and Window Width, then

```
def convert_file(dcm_file_path, jpg_file_path):
    dicom_img = dicom.read_file(dcm_file_path)
    img = dicom_img.pixel_array
    scaled_img = cv2.convertScaleAbs(img-window_center, alpha=(255.0 /window_width)
    cv2.imwrite(jpg_file_path, scaled_img)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But I just found that with the first code, the picture is too light to recognize, and with the second, it is a little dark.

Comment: I just realized a tiny mistake in the first code (subtracting `np.min(img)` from the denominator). You can see if that helps. And regarding it being light or dark, you can try changing the values of window width and center, because the second code is how DICOM Viewers render the image

Comment: And if the code helped, do select the answer as the right answer :)

Comment: This is helpful, but what if you want to re-save as a DICOM image. I have found that cv2.write won't accept .dcm as an extension

Comment: @GhostRider true. OpenCV doesn't support dcm out of the box. You would have to go for a library like pydicom